# How can an anonymous type object have convert to a string if it's not enumerable?

Tags: c#

Say I define a variable like this:

```
var o = new { RBI = 108, Name = "Roberto Alomar" };
```

I can do something like:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", o);
```

But if I try:

```
foreach (var i in o) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", o[i]);
}
```

I get an error:

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'AnonymousType#1' because 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

So how does it work under the hood? I'd think that a method for turning an object into a string would have to loop through all the properties to accomplish the task. Is there some special method that allows this to happen, or am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: Do you think there is a loop when you say 1.ToString()?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram thanks for the comment. I think it gave me the insight I needed.

Comment: Why would you think that, just because it probably has a loop *as an implementation detail,* that it should go out of its way (generating extra code and bloating your binary) just to surface the things it's looping over via an `IEnumerable` that nobody would ever use? You have some strange ideas about object-oriented design.

Comment: Are you by chance a JavaScript programmer?  The C# foreach loop is not the JavaScript for-in loop. The C# foreach loop enumerates the *members* of a *collection*. The JavaScript for-in loop enumerates the *properties* of an *object. They are similar, but quite different.

Comment: @EricLippert You caught me. I'd be happy to accept if you answered that with the detail fleshed out a little.

Comment: As an aside - I'm pretty sure it's Alomar. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How does it work under the hood? I'd think that a method for turning an object into a string would have to loop through all the properties to accomplish the task.

Your assumption is that the implementation of ToString is shared between all instances of all anonymous types; that, for example, there is some helper that is logically something like you would do in JavaScript:

```
var s = "";
for (property in this)
   s += property + ":" + this[property];
```

This assumption is wrong; there is no single one-size-fits-all implementation of ToString for anonymous types. Rather, the *compiler* knows what all the properties of the anonymous method are and so it generates a brand-new custom implementation of ToString for *every* distinct anonymous type.

In C#, the `foreach` loop does not do what the `for-in` loop does in JavaScript. The C# loop enumerates the *members of a collection*. The JS loop enumerates the *properties of an object*.

If you want to enumerate the properties of an object in C# you can do that, it just takes a bit more work:

```
var s = "";
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in this.GetType().GetProperties())
   s += propertyInfo.Name + ":" + propertyInfo.GetValue(this).ToString();
```

Comment: Just a minor caution: your code will fail if there are any indexed properties.

Comment: @kvb: Indeed; and what if the property is write-only? There are a number of problems with this sketch; it was not intended to be bulletproof.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that because anonymous types don't implements IEnumerable interface - it's not a collection just one object. You have to explicitly print the values.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", o.RBI);
Console.WriteLine("{0}", o.Name);
```

But step yourself back. Do you need anonymous type? Define your own custom type.

```
class MyType // give it more meaningful name 
{
     public int RBI { get; set;}
     public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All anonymous objects have the same methods.  They can be compared to each other as long as they have the same named fields with the same types, they all have a `ToString()` implementation that will give the string as you can see.  But they don't have an implementation of an enumerator.  Why should they?  It's not like Javascript in that sense where you can enumerate over the property names/indices/whatever because... it's C#, that's just not how it is.  Why would you think any different?

If you wanted something to work similarly, fortunately we have implicitly typed variables and reflection to help us out there.

```
var obj = new { Foo = "asd", Bar = "add", Gar = "123" };
var adapter = PropertyAdapter.Create(obj);
foreach (var name in adapter)
    Console.WriteLine("obj.{0} = {1}", name, adapter[name]);
```

```
public static class PropertyAdapter
{
    public static PropertyAdapter<T> Create<T>(T obj)
    {
        return new PropertyAdapter<T>(obj);
    }
}

public class PropertyAdapter<T> : IEnumerable<string>
{
    private T obj;
    public PropertyAdapter(T obj) { this.obj = obj; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return obj.ToString();
    }

    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(T).GetProperty(name).GetValue(obj, null);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return typeof(T)
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(pi => pi.Name)
            .GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: You caught me. I thought it would be like other languages I am more familiar with.

Answer (score -1):

When you do

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", o);
```

What's really happening is a call to Object.ToString(), which is inherited and has a built-in implementation for anonymous types that prints the properties and values.

On the other hand,

```
foreach (var i in o) { .. }
```

Can't work, because `o` must be an IEnumerable (or IEnumerable<>)

**EDIT**: <strike>The equivalent of what your expecting</strike> Enumerating over the string that is printed when using `WriteLine` can be achieved (for explanatory purposes, and otherwise useless) by doing:

```
foreach (var i in o.ToString()) { .. }
```

However as Jeff Mercado points out, that is not what you seem to want (it won't iterate over the properties - only over the individual characters of the already-formatted string)

Comment: He's not trying to iterate over the characters of the string representation (at least it doesn't seem that way), but rather trying to enumerate over the fields of the object and access its values.  Similar to how Javascript is.

Comment: This isn't correct - the compiler overrides the `object.ToString` method for anonymous types with a type specific version. Nothing is inherited.